# how i will get the Error Text inside the sfForm in symfony framework?

Tags: symfony1

I have sfForm and when the program run this line was run

$this->addMessage('invalid_format', 'The following addresses are incorrect: %emails%.');
then i want when the user entered a invalid value, show to him the previous text bye using the function which the sfForm has like getValidatorSchema(), and the variables inside this function.
so, what is the way and right syntax to do it?!!

Comment: Are you sure that the issue is about Symfony2? It looks like Symfony1.

Answer (score 0):

http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/forms/1_4/en/02-Form-Validation

The standard email validator re-populates the entered value when the bind() method is called.

Using the validator, you can simply change the message.

```
array('invalid' => 'Please enter a valid email address (ex: user@domain.com).'
```